# Socket emit doesnt work right with setInterval

Tags: javascript, socket.io

The problem is that at first when I join the game the `ingame` is set to false and user can join the game in real time with button click and user `ingame` becomes to true. Even though user is not in game, the monster still attacks every five seconds, but if user is not in game his HP not touched with the monster damage. Let's say at that time the monster attack ten times when player `ingame` was set to `false`. After then I click the button to join the game, and immediatelly all ten attacks are sent to the user. What can cause this problem ?

```
setInterval(() => {
    let monsterDamage = Math.floor(Math.random() * monsters[defeats.defeats].damageB) + monsters[defeats.defeats].damageA;

    User.findOne({username: username, ingame: true}).then((user) => {
            user.hp -= monsterDamage;
            user.save();
    });

    io.emit('monster-attack', {
        damage: monsterDamage
    });
    console.log(monsterDamage);
}, 5000);
```

VueJS:

```
        socket.on('monster-attack', (data) => {
            if(this.ingame) {
            this.userHP = this.userHP - data.damage;
            this.userBar = (this.userHP / this.userMaxHP) * 100;
                if(this.userHP < 0) {
                    this.userHP = 0;
                }
            }
            this.monsterDamage = data.damage;
            this.monsterDamageVisible = true;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.monsterDamageVisible = false;
            }, 1000);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In line with your example, in your vue code, when you receive the socket data, what is the value of damange? Is it the sum of all the attacks?

Comment: I receive socket data when I login to the game. Because servers sends monster damage on `io.on('connection'....)`. Monster damage is set in the example above `monsterDamage` variable. It's taken from `JSON` file.

Comment: you send data every 5 seconds, you dont have any condition for send data, only when you receive that data.
What happens if you try this?
setInterval(() => {
    let monsterDamage = Math.floor(Math.random() * monsters[defeats.defeats].damageB) + monsters[defeats.defeats].damageA;

    User.findOne({username: username, ingame: true}).then((user) => {
            user.hp -= monsterDamage;
            user.save();

            io.emit('monster-attack', {
              damage: monsterDamage
            });
    });

    
    console.log(monsterDamage);
}, 5000);